# concatenate strings in sqlite sum strings

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this syntax in sql:

```
UPDATE fazerbem_carrinho_historico 
SET pendencia_pago = '10.00', 
    pendenciahistorico = pendenciahistorico + '12' 
WHERE data_compra = '76'
```

Assuming that within the `pendenciahistorio` column already has the `'16'` value, what should happen and so I give the update, store the value `1612`, but they save the sum of `16 + 12`, since the `pendenciahistorico` column is a varchar, how can solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `||` operator is used to ***concatenate*** strings together in SQLLite:

```
UPDATE fazerbem_carrinho_historico 
SET pendencia_pago = '10.00', 
    pendenciahistorico = pendenciahistorico || '12' 
WHERE data_compra = '76'
```

Answer (score 0):

For string concatenation, use `||`:

```
UPDATE fazerbem_carrinho_historico
    SET pendencia_pago = '10.00',
        pendenciahistorico = pendenciahistorico || '12'
    WHERE data_compra = '76';
```